# Если ли разница между метками "синтаксис" и "синтаксический-разбор"?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Если ли разница между метками "синтаксис" и "синтаксический-разбор"? В чем она? Не следует ли их объединить?

P.S. Система не пропускала этот мой вопрос, утверждая, что он не отвечает стандартам качества. Где можно прочитать об этих стандартах?

Answer (score 2):

Я думал над этим вопросом и пришел к выводу, что метки типа [синтаксический-разбор](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80) имеют право на существование, потому что действительно уточняют суть вопроса.

Представьте: человек хочет найти все вопросы, в которых помогли разобраться с составом предложения. Если мы оставим только метку [синтаксис](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81), ему придется пробирать через дебри; если же мы введем метку [синтаксический-разбор](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80), он сможет найти искомое с помощью одного клика.

Стандарты качества: тело вопроса должно содержать не менее 30 символов, заголовок — не менее 15.

Comment: ОК, теперь я стараюсь добавить метку "синтаксический-разбор", если вижу вопрос о составе предложения. Но что делать, если такой вопрос помечен как "синтаксис"? Добавлять "синтаксический-разбор" или ставить его вместо "синтаксис"?

Comment: Я бы не трогал "синтаксис", просто добавил "синтаксический-разбор". В моем представлении, "синтаксический-разбор" является частью группы меток "синтаксис". Это значит, что метка по-любому связана с синтаксисом.